# Overriding default legend glyph colors in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I've got a Bokeh scatterplot that splits by color and glyph.

I've consolidated my legend so that it only contains glyphs. Bokeh appears to be filling the glyphs with some average (or random, not sure) color fill and border. I'd rather they be just a single color, like black. Does anybody know how to override default legend glyph colors? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete minimal code sample.